# Download Ubuntu Bionic Packages Offline

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

Is there a way to get all the bionic packages from [this site](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/allpackages) locally so that I can send them to a Linux VM (which does not have any internet access) using pscp on my Windows machine?

I tried following the steps [from Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Offline/Repository)  but I can't seem to download these files from the [archive site](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/):

- InRelease
- Release
- Release.gpg

I've used Chrome, IE, Edge (thinking it was a browser problem) and all I get, when I click each link, is a new tab with the contents of each file.

The hard way of doing it has been to download each package, send it to the VM, and dpkg it. However, some packages need dependencies and I'm constantly having to go back and forth downloading dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly your only problem is downloading a text file that your browser opens directly instead of prompting for a download. If so, you can do either of those things:

1. Right click the link and select "Save link as..." (or your browser's equivalent) instead of left clicking
2. Press [ctrl]+s when viewing the file in your browser.

Both of these will prompt your browser to download the file instead of displaying it.